# local libraries in xamarin not updating

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I've developed a project in windows,later i loaded into my mac mini it was running fine,then i've seen package updates available ,when updated i got 39 errors saying

/Users/xxxx/Projects/TimeSheet/TimeSheet: Error XA5209: Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the /Users/xxxxx/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView/23.3.0.0/content directory. (XA5209) (TimeSheet)

when i checked this  directory ""/Users/xxxxx/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView/23.3.0.0/  """"  there was nothing updated in 23.3.0.0 Folder in mac.is there any restriction is there guys? please help me

Thank you

Comment: did you download the file as instructed and manually unzip it in the proper folder?

Comment: no i did'nt downloaded ,can you provide any links to download?

Comment: it says "please download xxx" in the error message you posted, and gives a url.  The url is even a clickable link in your post!

Comment: i've download and extracted but still errors facing

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to download the latest Android support libraries since Xamarin uses an older version. They take longer to update since they need to do the translation.

The current version that is compatible is `23.0.1.3`.

See the [Troubleshooting](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/) guide for more information.